# Placing objects on another objects faces

Tags: objects, faces

I'm trying to model a strawberry and want the seeds to be placed on the faces of a mesh. Like in the picture. Is there an automatic way to do this? I've tried using hair particles but it's too random. I want neat lines. I've also tried to use arrays and curve modifiers but it's clunky and feels like there should be an easier way.

Thanks

[image: strawberry]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical use case for geometry nodes.

Use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

and with this node setup:

[image]

you can do this:

[image]

*** UPDATE ***

i just found out a more elegant way doing this:

[image]

```
Note: this simple solution might not look that good at the top and the bottom, but here you can use the technique from the first part of my answer to cut them off.
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want!! I'm completely new to geometry nodes, though. I can't find "instance on points", just "point instance" which doesn't have the same in/outputs. The position node can't be found either, but guessing it's something similar to the "math" node that has a different name when it's properties are changed.

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks! Now I have to figure out how to make it skip every other instance and offset by 1 each row. :) :)

Comment: just ask this as a new question...i will answer! ;)

Comment: Just did! Thanks in advance :– )

Comment: @Chris Why he should ask a new Q? I think your A needs improvements. Strawberry pattern is like rhombus, your pattern is squared.

Comment: @vklidu: i updated my answer